# API 1 Key signup for google map

Tags: google-maps, api-key

I have a Problem generating API Key in google maps, google tells me :

> The fingerprint you entered is not valid, Please press the Back button
>   on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're entering a hash for your certificate in order to create a [Google Maps Android API v.1 key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup).

The error message is because your hash does not match the security certificate's actual MD5 signature.

It may be that you're copying the SHA-1 value in, which is displayed by default in the newest JRE. To get the MD5 hash, run the `keytool` program with the `-list -v` parameters, e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool -list -v
```

Your local keystore's certificate hashes should be displayed in the console.